# Google Cloud VPN error: peer didn't accept DH group MODP_1024, it requested MODP_1024

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an issue with Google Cloud Platform, punctually with a VPN that we have mounted between our client and GCP, we have falls in a fixed period of approximately 5 hours. (5 hours up and 5 hours down.)

The issue is:

peer didn't accept DH group MODP_1024, it requested MODP_1024

The usually is 5 hours up and 5 hours down.
https : // i.stack.imgur.com/tWU66.png

Our client receives the following information
https : // i.stack.imgur.com/za5xo.png

The complete log is:

```
{
"textPayload": "peer didn't accept DH group MODP_1024, it requested MODP_1024"   
"insertId": "1xygt3f4zil3t"   
"resource": {
    "type": "vpn_gateway"    
    "labels": {
        "gateway_id": "3128708644582367778"     
        "project_id": "xxxxxxx-compensar"     
        "region": "us-west1"     
        }
    }
"timestamp": "2017-05-26T20:47:44.780876927Z"   
"severity": "DEBUG"   
"logName": "projects/xxxxxxx-compensar/logs/cloud.googleapis.com%2Fipsec_events"   
"receiveTimestamp": "2017-05-26T20:47:44.825563989Z"   
}
```

The configuration on Client Services is:
https : // i.stack.imgur.com/eyMd4.png

The configuration on GCP is:

```
{
"creationTimestamp": "2017-02-20T08:43:58.085-08:00",
"description": "",
"forwardingRules": [
    "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/forwardingRules/cliente-chile-vpn-rule-udp4500",
    "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/forwardingRules/cliente-chile-vpn-rule-udp500",
    "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/forwardingRules/cliente-chile-vpn-rule-esp"
],
"id": "3128708644582367778",
"kind": "compute#targetVpnGateway",
"name": "cliente-chile-vpn",
"network": "projects/xxxxxxx/global/networks/cliente-chile",
"region": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1",
"selfLink": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/targetVpnGateways/cliente-chile-vpn",
"status": "READY",
"tunnels": [
    "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/vpnTunnels/cliente-chile-vpn-tunnel-1"
]
}

{
"creationTimestamp": "2017-05-24T12:46:01.059-07:00",
"description": "",
"detailedStatus": "Handshake with peer broken for unknown reason. Trying again soon.",
"id": "5377869613206363158",
"ikeVersion": 2,
"kind": "compute#vpnTunnel",
"localTrafficSelector": [
    "10.110.0.0/20",
    "10.100.0.0/20"
],
"name": "cliente-chile-vpn-tunnel-1",
"peerIp": "000.00.00.00",
"region": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1",
"selfLink": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/vpnTunnels/cliente-chile-vpn-tunnel-1",
"sharedSecret": "*************",
"sharedSecretHash": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"status": "FIRST_HANDSHAKE",
"targetVpnGateway": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/targetVpnGateways/cliente-chile-vpn"
}

{
"creationTimestamp": "2017-02-20T08:44:05.802-08:00",
"description": "",
"IPAddress": "104.196.229.158",
"IPProtocol": "UDP",
"id": "7352555096091566650",
"kind": "compute#forwardingRule",
"loadBalancingScheme": "EXTERNAL",
"name": "cliente-chile-vpn-rule-udp4500",
"portRange": "4500-4500",
"region": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1",
"selfLink": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/forwardingRules/cliente-chile-vpn-rule-udp4500",
"target": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/targetVpnGateways/cliente-chile-vpn"
}

{
"creationTimestamp": "2017-02-20T08:44:04.428-08:00",
"description": "",
"IPAddress": "104.196.229.158",
"IPProtocol": "UDP",
"id": "8789138583346127419",
"kind": "compute#forwardingRule",
"loadBalancingScheme": "EXTERNAL",
"name": "cliente-chile-vpn-rule-udp500",
"portRange": "500-500",
"region": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1",
"selfLink": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/forwardingRules/cliente-chile-vpn-rule-udp500",
"target": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/targetVpnGateways/cliente-chile-vpn"
}

{
"creationTimestamp": "2017-02-20T08:44:03.043-08:00",
"description": "",
"IPAddress": "104.196.229.158",
"IPProtocol": "ESP",
"id": "2497873112390345276",
"kind": "compute#forwardingRule",
"loadBalancingScheme": "EXTERNAL",
"name": "cliente-chile-vpn-rule-esp",
"region": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1",
"selfLink": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/forwardingRules/cliente-chile-vpn-rule-esp",
"target": "projects/xxxxxxx/regions/us-west1/targetVpnGateways/cliente-chile-vpn"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things, First looking at the client configuration it appears that the key renegotiation parameters are mismatched [1], fixing that may help with the timing disconnects.

The Rejection errors I believe are because cloud VPN is attempting to establish 2 Child SAs, one for each of your networks listed, one is established, the other seems to be rejected.

One option would be to change the Cloud VPN tunnel to have 0.0.0.0/0 on the remote side, and then set up 2 routes manually for your two remote networks inside GCP.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced#supported_ike_ciphers

Answer (score 1):

Your Screenshot shows two mismatches from the [Cloud VPN docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns#setting_up_the_peer_vpn_gateway):

- You use SHA-256 when SHA-1 is required
- Cloud VPN uses pre-shared keys, but it looks like no pre-shared secret is set up.

IPSec requires configurations to match closely, so try swiching to SHA-1 and ensuring the two sides of the VPN have the same pre-shared key.